# New SeleniumManager api in Selenium 4.6.0 - Error: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 102?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, chromedriver

I am using new Selenium Manager functionality in the 4.6.0 version. However, it is downloading the Chromedriver.exe in the .cache folder, but its not compatible with the Chrome Browser.

**Chrome Browser version:** Version 107.0.5304.107 (Official Build) (64-bit)

C:\Users....cache\selenium\chromedriver\win32\107.0.5304.62\chromedriver.exe

```
public class Test1 {
    private WebDriver driver;

    @Test
    public void loginTest() throws InterruptedException {

        String dpath = SeleniumManager.getInstance().getDriverPath("chromedriver");
        System.out.println(dpath);

        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://accounts.lambdatest.com/login");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    }

}
```

Error I got:

```
    FAILED: loginTest
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 102
Current browser version is 107.0.5304.107 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is now resolved. There was a chromedriver.exe file in the project root folder. So, there was a conflict. AFter i removed this exe, it ran successfully! :)